# How to transfer learning or fine tune YOLOv4-darknet with freeze some layers?

Tags: object-detection, yolo, transfer-learning, darknet, yolov4

I'm a beginner in object detection field.

First, I followed YOLOv4 custom-train from [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mmj3nxGT2YQ), I have successfully followed the tutorial. Then I started to think that if I have a new task which is similar to YOLOv4 pre-trained (which using COCO 80 classes) and I have only small dataset size, then I think it would be great if I can fine tune the model (unfreeze only the last layer) to keep or even to increase the detector performance by using only small & similar dataset. [This reference](https://towardsdatascience.com/transfer-learning-from-pre-trained-models-f2393f124751) seems to legitimate my thought about the fine-tuning I wanted to do.

Then I go to Alexey github [here](https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet#yolo-v4-v3-and-v2-for-windows-and-linux) to check how to freeze layers, and found that I should use `stopbackward=1`. It says that

> "...set param stopbackward=1 for layer-136 in cfg-file"

But I have no idea about where is "layer-136" in the cfg-file [here](https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet/blob/master/cfg/yolov4-custom.cfg) and also I have no idea where to put `stopbackward=1` if I only want to unfreeze the last layer (with freezing all the other layers). So to summarize my questions.

1. Where (in which line) to put `stopbackward=1` in the yolov4-custom.cfg if I want to unfreeze last layer and freeze the other layers?
2. What is "layer-136" which mentioned in Alexey github reference? (is it one of the classifier layer? or else?)
3. In which line of yolov4-custom.cfg should I put the `stopbackward=1` for that layer-136?

Any further information from you is really appreciated. Please advise.

Thank you in advance.

Regards,
Sona

Answer (score 1):

the "layer-136" is located before the head of yolov4. To make it easy to see, try to visualize the .cfg file to [Netron apps](https://netron.app/) and read the .cfg via text editor, so you can understand the location of layer. You can notice the input and output (the x-layer) when you analyze it with Netron

Comment: Thanks a lot! it really helps me to see the config better.